# Simulink - Aircraft model with desired bank, pitch, yaw as input and accelerations, rates as outputs

Tags: navigation, accelerometer, simulink, gyroscope, euler-angles

I am developing a Simulink model to validate an attitude algorithm. I would like to compare some known inputs/outputs from a standard Simulink block to the ones obtained via my algorithm to validate its design.

At the moment, I am using the 6DOF(quaternion) block of the aerospace toolbox but I find it really hard to set up the right forces and moments (and mass and inertia of the A/C) that it expects to produce appropriate outputs (I am interested in Accelerations and Rates along with its Pitch and Roll signals).

Does anyone know of another quick solution to have an aircraft model where the inputs is the desired bank angle for example and its output are still the ones cited here above (acc, gyros, pitch, roll)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have the following book? http://www.amazon.com/Aircraft-Control-Simulation-Brian-Stevens/dp/0471371459 There used to be a Simulink model of an F16 based on that book. I might still have it.

Comment: unfortunately not. Any free to grab model around?

Comment: thanks a lot. Do you also have a link for the book itself or that part only of the book?

Comment: Basically, what I am looking for is to create a control loop which neglects aerodynamics and environmental effects, also I can neglect the actuator's dynamics and have only a feedback loop acting on the error_DCM (resulting from the matrix product of actual_DCM x desired_DCM). The tough thing is to design the controller which given this error, it just outputs the right forces and moments acting on centre of gravity of the A/C model to achieve the desired set point.